# Allow duplicate keys in array from inner join

Tags: javascript, arrays, inner-join

I'm making an web application in **node.js** and i've made a query to get user data from a USERS table, and at the same time get rewards from a REWARD table. I need only 1 row from the USERS table, but (maybe) multiple ones from the REWARDS table.

`SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN rewards r ON u.ID = r.uid WHERE u.id = '+uid;`

The output:

```
{ ID: 2,
  username: 'hi',
  password: 'password',
  userlevel: 10,
  balance: 500,
  bonusbalance: 0,
  level: 3,
  lprogress: 2,
  RID: 4,
  uid: 2,
  reward: '25 FREE bonus balance!' }
```

This looks like its exactly what I want, however there are multiple rows that meet the query requirements for the REWARDS table (the REWARDS table output starts from RID onwards).

The problem is that javascript overwrites the keys (RID, uid, reward) with the last row from the REWARDS table. How can I get all rewards linked to a single user ID? I would prefer using SQL to grab the right data, but a javascript solution would be ok as well.

**My solution**

I just used 2 queries in 2 different functions, this is the full code, maybe someone finds it useful.

Full code:

```
    getUser: function(uid, callback) {
  q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = '+uid;
  doQuery(q, function(user) {
    getRewards(uid, function(rewards) {
      if (rewards === false) {
        callback(user[0]);
      } else {
        user[0]['rewards'] = new Array();
        rewards.forEach(function(reward) {
          user[0]['rewards'].push(reward);
        });
        console.log(user[0]);
        callback(user[0]);
      }
    });
  });
}

<snip>


function getRewards(uid, callback) {
  q = 'SELECT * FROM rewards WHERE uid = '+uid;
  doQuery(q, function(rewards) {
    callback(rewards);
  });
}

function doQuery(query, callback) {
  sql.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query('use casino');
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) {
              callback(err);
            } else {
              if (rows.length == 0) {
                callback(false);
              } else {
                callback(rows);
              }
            }
        });
   });
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ ID: 2,
  username: 'hi',
  password: 'password',
  userlevel: 10,
  balance: 5000,
  bonusbalance: 0,
  level: 3,
  lprogress: 36,
  rewards:
   [ { RID: 1, uid: 2, reward: 'One FREE scratch card!', level: 2 },
     { RID: 2, uid: 2, reward: '25 FREE bonus balance', level: 3 } ] }
```

Comment: Is this a "has many" relationship?

Comment: The 2 tables have no relationship as far as i know (i'm pretty new with db stuff)

Comment: What do you want the output data to look like?

Comment: And what does your JS parse function look like? What environment is this in? Node?

Comment: Yes this is node.js, i'm sorry for not including this. Will add more info.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson: well I'd like to get **all** rewards from a single user in the return data. At the moment it just shows the latest (overwrites array keys).

Comment: So what I see here is that `rows` returns the json from above since you're just logging it out?

Comment: The array output part was output from when i did console.log(user[0]); instead of just 'user'.

Comment: Your first step is to design the data structure that you need. To store multiple values for `RID`, `uid`, etc. then likely they should be arrays so that you have `{..., RID:[4,2,...], uid:[2,4,3,...], ...}`. If that's what you want, help can be provided on how to get there.

Comment: RobG: yes that would be great!